# How to know (better by GUI) the "average" nb of Triangles, Average Number of Vertices and Average nb Draw Calls in the whole game in Unity 5?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I know that there is a Statistics pane and that Unity has a profiler tool. So please don't include these in your answers.
I need a way to get precisely the **Average** of nb of Triangles, Vertices and Draw calls of a game (as a whole). I want to get the average of these numbers in the whole game so I can differ between different games or 3D Worlds in terms of graphical complexity. Thanks for any help

Comment: So do you want precise or average number?

Comment: I want average number only. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want use `UnityEditor.UnityStats`?

Comment: UnityStats class allows a person to retrieve the nb of drawCalls, Nb of Triangles and Nb of Vertices. How to get the average of these numbers (just the averages) on the whole game? Is there any method by GUI to do this? I have a huge number of games I need to extract this information from them. If GUI method is not possible: Do you have an easy code to extract these numbers (averages)?

Comment: I did not get any useful answer yet!!???